# How to call an Abstract Class extending Service or a Thread in the Main Activity?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an abstract class that extends either a service or a thread. This is because i must run this class every second to find out the foreground activity. If its Service i'm using Runnable and make it run every second using Handler. But I'm unable to Start the service or thread from the main activity. I know that abstract classes cant be instantiated but is there any work around that i could use over here?? Please, help.

```
    public abstract class A extends Service Implements Interface {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);
}
   protected abstract void getData();

   public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        //Trying to find Foreground Activities

        A start = new B();
        start.getData();

mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);
 }
};

//Inteface methods defined here.
}
```

Another class:

```
public class B extends A {

    public void getData() {
      //Do my stuff
    }
}
```

Now I need to call this A class, so that this abstract method can be executed in which ever class I extend A.

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate an abstract class('s anonymous subclass):

```
abstract class AbstractClass {}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle i) {
      AbstractClass abstractInstance = new AbstractClass(){};
   }
}
```

Though actually you are not supposed to need to do this. What I would suggest is a simple JavaSE concurrency based approach, using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: @ PeterVarga : AS u can see my updated question, A class executes B classes getData since B extends A. Like this, I can create many classes that extends A, so that in all classes same operation goes on. If I start A class from main activity, then all classes that extends A will run simultaneously. I hope u understood my problem. Please help.